# Can I use helpers from actions?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm trying to use helpers from actions in this way:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('I18N', 'Asset', 'Url'));
echo image_tag('bullet_red.png');
echo link_to('Ver detalles', 'ver-detalles/' . $record->getIdregistros(), 'class="btn btn-success btn-mini"');
```

But I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function _parse_attributes() in
>   /var/www/html/monitor/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/helper/AssetHelper.php on
>   line 333

Why?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski yes, it was I said to the other users that leave me a reply, I move into a clean solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

_parse_attributes() function is located in the Tag Helper.

so you will have to import the Tag Helper as well

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(array('I18N', 'Asset', 'Url', 'Tag'));
```

Comment: yes I found a post similar to my problem but also said that isn't correct to use helpers from within actions/controllers and that breaks complety MVC, so I go ahead for a more clean solution anyway thanks